# Can you make an item teleport someone to spawn in Minecraft 1.13.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I run a realms server and I am trying to figure out if there is a way to teleport someone to spawn or their home if they use /drop an item. It looks like there is a way to do this on 1.8, but I am having issues running the commands needed to do it in 1.13.2.

Answer (score 0):

Make an end portal and name the item you want, and then make a command that if you dropped this item it will teleport you to the coordinates where the end portal is. You can make a button in the End that teleport them to the end portal, after you beat the ender dragon, and like this, however, they will teleport back to their spawn point.